# jquery event on hashed div

Tags: jquery, hash

I have a page with a lot of divs, and I want to direct users to a certain div using #DIV_NAME
and highlight that div.

I tried it with JQUERY

```
    var hasih = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $('div#'+hasih).addClass("div_highlight");
```

and it works only if I load the page once, then refresh.

how can I make it work on the first time the page is loaded?

tnx

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the effect we get in Stack Overflow when we click any new news in inbox, we click on it; the page lodes and the news item is highlighted for a short duration?

Comment: something like that, yeah. I want a permanent like to a page that highlights a div within the page

Comment: Just bind it to the load and hashchange event: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12447340/1250044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, you can achieve this effect in css-only, without javascript.

CSS 3 introduces the new `:target` pseudo-classe [<sup>[more info]</sup>](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/).

> The :target pseudo selector in CSS matches when the hash in the URL
>   and the id of an element are the same.

Here is a simple example (**[demo js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3637q/)**):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#first">first</a> - <a href="#second">second</a> - <a href="#third">third</a>

<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;            
}

div:target{
    border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('href');        
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
    }, 500,'',function(){
        $(selector).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);                             
    });
    return false;
});
```

[**Here is the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gZSE5/11/)

***Dont forget to include jQuery UI***

Comment: thanks, actually i wanted to call this function from the url, so what i did was set a variable to check if theres a div name in the url and then do the function you gave me. anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('load hashchange', function() {
    var hasih = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $('div').removeClass('div_highlight');
    $('div#' + hasih).addClass("div_highlight");
});
```

---

Just switch the url between

http://jsfiddle.net/KWTmm/show/#hash1

http://jsfiddle.net/KWTmm/show/#hash2